# Why can't I call create on this has_one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm missing something basic. This is Rails 3.2.16.

In my app:

```
User has_one Subscription
Subscription belongs_to User
Subscription belongs_to Plan
```

But when I try to do this:

```
user.subscription.create(plan_id: plan.id)
```

I get the following:

```
NoMethodError: private method `create' called for #<Subscription:0x007f80f1f4dfc0>
```

Yet this works fine:

```
Subscription.create(user_id: user.id, plan_id: plan.id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for this method:

```
user.create_subscription(plan_id: plan.id)
```

[From the RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference):

> When initializing a new has_one or belongs_to association you must use the build_ prefix to build the association, rather than the association.build method that would be used for has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many associations. To create one, use the create_ prefix.

Comment: Can we get Subscription.user ??? benjaminjosephw @benjaminjosephw

Answer (score 2):

In your models you should have the associations like this:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription 
end
```

Read [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I think this is what AKWF already has with an additional `Subscription belongs_to Plan` association.

Answer (score 2):

one way to do that

```
user.subscription = Subscription.create(plan_id: plan.id)
```